# generating map from list of objects having a map using java lambda8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I've an object,

```
class Object2{
     String name;
     String id;
     Map<String, String> customData;
}

class Object1{
     List<Object2> obj1List;
}
```

I want to convert this customData Map in the List of object1 into one single map, I am ok with over-writing the values if the key already exists.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way with lambdas and Java 8:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
object1List.forEach(o1 -> 
        o1.getObject1List().forEach(o2 -> map.putAll(o2.getCustomData())));
```

Comment: weird naming convention in the question, but I guess you meant `getObject1List()`

Answer (score 3):

Use `flatMap` and `toMap` as follows:

```
List<Object1> source = ...
Map<String, String> result = 
     source.stream()
           .flatMap(e -> e.getObj1List().stream()
                               .flatMap(a -> a.getCustomData().entrySet().stream()))
           .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (l, r) -> r));
```

or if you're dealing with a single `Object1` object:

```
Object1 myObj = ...
Map<String, String> result = 
      myObj.getObj1List()
           .stream()
           .flatMap(a -> a.getCustomData().entrySet().stream())
           .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (l, r) -> r));
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can perform [`Stream.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) and then use [`Map.putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) as

```
List<Object1> object1s = new ArrayList<>(); // initialise as you would
Map<String, String> finalCustomData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
object1s.stream() // Stream<Object1>
        .flatMap(o1 -> o1.getObj1List().stream()) // Stream<Object2>
        .map(Object2::getCustomData) // Stream<Map<String, String>>
        .forEach(finalCustomData::putAll);
```